# "Шепнуть на ушко" — ударение

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно: *шепнуть на **у**шко* или *шепнуть на ушк**о**?*

Первый вариант точно слышал, но нет полной уверенности, что он правильный и единственный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Русское словесное ударение (М. В. Зарва):
**ушко**
1. **у́шко**, -а; **но**: *за ушко́ да на со́лнышко* (поговорка); *для ми́лого дружка́ и серёжку из ушка́* (пословица); *мн.* у́шки, у́шек; у́шки на маку́шке (уменьш. к у́хо).
2. **ушко́**, -а́; *мн.* ушки́, -о́в (отверстие у иголки; приспособление для держания, подвешивания у пуговицы, медали, колокола, ушата).

Словарь трудностей русского языка (Н. Еськова):
[**у́шки**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=vFimCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA429&lpg=PA429&dq=%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=wlOqCowkUY&sig=ACfU3U1FW74m9e8J3qnNw-XGInHcQVe63Q&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDxIKPxJ_iAhUJposKHdWHDSgQ6AEwB3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&f=false), у́шек, у́шкам, *ед.* **у́шко**, -а и *допуст.* ушко́, -а́; **на ушко́ (шептать, шепнуть)**… *Уменьш.* к уши, ухо.
*...ушку́ девическому
                в завиточках волоска
с полупохабщины
               не разалеться тронуту*.
В. Маяковский (1929-1930)

*Ты на куче сетей.

Ты курлычешь,

Как ключ, балагуря,

И, как прядь за ушко́м,

Чуть щекочет струя за кормой.*
Б. Пастернак (1944)

Дискуссий по поводу правильного ударения немало ([АиФ](http://www.aif.ru/society/education/igolnoe_u_shko_ili_ushko_kak_pravilno) и [Екатеринбург](https://www.ekburg.ru/news/18/68021-kak-pravilno-igolnoe-ushko-ili-ushko/)).

Можно сделать такой вывод: **шепнуть на у́шко** — правильно (нейтрально, современно).
Если же вы в какой-то ситуации скажете **шепнуть на ушко́** — это будет *допустимо* и очень близко к "поговорочному варианту" (то есть охарактеризует вас как знатока русских поговорок).

Comment: Спасибо, Римма!

Comment: Здравствуйте, Римма! Я правильно понимаю, что старое ударение на второй слог: "ушк**о**"? В частности и "шепнуть на ушк**о**" соответствует нормам XIX и первой части XX века. Верно?

Comment: Да, я думаю, что так оно и есть. В словаре Ушакова (1935-1940) даются оба варианта (без каких-либо пометок): у́шко, а, и ушко́1, а́, мн. у́шки, у́шек, у́шкам, у́шках, ср. Уменьш.-ласкат. к ухо в 1, 2 и 4 знач. Маленькое у́шко. Шепну вам на ушко́. Некрасов. (https://lexicography.online/explanatory/ushakov/%D1%83/%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE) В некоторых версиях этого словаря **ушко́** стоит первым. P. S.  Интересно получилось — ушко у Ушакова.

Comment: *В некоторых версиях этого словаря ушко́ стоит первым.* Отлично! Мне почему-то нравится это старое ударение, по крайней мере в этом выражении и тех пословице и поговорке. *Интересно получилось — ушко у Ушакова.* Точно!))